# how to normalize input data for models in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

My training data are saved in 3 files, each file is too large and cannot fit into memory.For each training example, the data are two dimensionality (2805 rows and 222 columns, the 222nd column is for label) and are numerical values. I would like to normalize the data before feeding into models for training. Below is my code for input_pipeline, and 
the data has not been normalized before creating dataset. Is there some functions in tensorflow that can do normalization for my case?

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset([file1, file2, file3])
# combine 2805 lines into a single example
dataset = dataset.batch(2805)

def parse_example(line_batch):
    record_defaults = [[1.0] for col in range(0, 221)]
    record_defaults.append([1])
    content = tf.decode_csv(line_batch, record_defaults = record_defaults, field_delim = '\t')
    features = tf.stack(content[0:221])
    features = tf.transpose(features)
    label = content[-1][-1]
    label = tf.one_hot(indices = tf.cast(label, tf.int32), depth = 2)
    return features, label

dataset = dataset.map(parse_example)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000)
# batch multiple examples
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
data_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are different ways of "normalizing data". Depending which one you have in mind, it may or may not be easy to implement in your case.

### 1. Fixed normalization

If you know the fixed range(s) of your values (e.g. feature #1 has values in `[-5, 5]`, feature #2 has values in `[0, 100]`, etc.), you could easily pre-process your `feature` tensor in `parse_example()`, e.g.:

```python
def normalize_fixed(x, current_range, normed_range):
    current_min, current_max = tf.expand_dims(current_range[:, 0], 1), tf.expand_dims(current_range[:, 1], 1)
    normed_min, normed_max = tf.expand_dims(normed_range[:, 0], 1), tf.expand_dims(normed_range[:, 1], 1)
    x_normed = (x - current_min) / (current_max - current_min)
    x_normed = x_normed * (normed_max - normed_min) + normed_min
    return x_normed

def parse_example(line_batch, 
                  fixed_range=[[-5, 5], [0, 100], ...],
                  normed_range=[[0, 1]]):
    # ...
    features = tf.transpose(features)
    features = normalize_fixed(features, fixed_range, normed_range)
    # ...
```

### 2. Per-sample normalization

If your features are supposed to have approximately the same range of values, per-sample normalization could also be considered, i.e. applying normalization considering the features moments (mean, variance) for each sample:

```python
def normalize_with_moments(x, axes=[0, 1], epsilon=1e-8):
    mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(x, axes=axes)
    x_normed = (x - mean) / tf.sqrt(variance + epsilon) # epsilon to avoid dividing by zero
    return x_normed

def parse_example(line_batch):
    # ...
    features = tf.transpose(features)
    features = normalize_with_moments(features)
    # ...
```

### 3. Batch normalization

You could apply the same procedure over a complete batch instead of per-sample, which may make the process more stable:

```python
data_batch = normalize_with_moments(data_batch, axis=[1, 2])
```

Similarly, you could use [`tf.nn.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization)

### 4. Dataset normalization

Normalizing using the mean/variance computed over the whole dataset would be the trickiest, since as you mentioned it is a large, split one.

`tf.data.Dataset` isn't really meant for such global computation. A solution would be to use whatever tools you have to pre-compute the dataset moments, then use this information for your TF pre-processing.

---

As mentioned by @MiniQuark, Tensorflow has a [Transform](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform) library you could use to preprocess your data. Have a look at the [Get Started](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/get_started.md), or for instance at the [`tft.scale_to_z_score()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/6e99104b9d84991ef0836d376eda5932d77bca4f/tensorflow_transform/mappers.py#L152) method for sample normalization.

Comment: You may want to mention TensorFlow Transform, https://github.com/tensorflow/transform .

Comment: @MiniQuark I somehow didn't know of this library... Thanks for the mention (and for the previous correction)!

Comment: Thanks for both of your help. @MiniQuark @ Aldream

Comment: Great post, thx! For newbies like me: If you want this procedure over a complete batch just use axes=[0,1,2].

Answer (score 20):

Exapnding on benjaminplanche's answer for "#4 Dataset normalization", there is actually a pretty easy way to accomplish this.

Tensorflow's Keras provides a [preprocessing normalization layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Normalization). Now as this is a layer, its intent is to be used within the model. However you don't have to (more on that later).

The model usage is simple:

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=dataset.element_spec.shape)
norm = tf.keras.layers.preprocessing.Normalization()
norm.adapt(dataset) # you can use dataset.take(N) if N samples is enough for it to figure out the mean & variance.
layer1 = norm(input)
...
```

The advantage of using it in the model is that the normalization mean & variance are saved as part of the model weights. So when you load the saved model, it'll use the same values it was trained with.

As mentioned earlier, if you don't want to use keras models, you don't have to use the layer as part of one. If you'd rather use it in your dataset pipeline, you can do that too.

```
norm = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
norm.adapt(dataset)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda t: norm(t))
```

The disadvantage is that you need to save and restore those weights manually now (`norm.get_weights()` and `norm.set_weights()`). Numpy has convenient [`save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`load()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) functions you can use here.

```
np.save("norm_weights.npy", norm.get_weights())
norm.set_weights(np.load("norm_weights.npy", allow_pickle=True))
```

Comment: Hi，@Patrick，I just TF1.12  and Keras 2.2.4, I had this error, module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental', is there any old API for using '''module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental''''?

Comment: I think using the normalization in the model is not a good idea, so I don't want to use norm layer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

After defining `inputs`, execute the following line of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(
    axis=-1,
    center=True,
    scale=True,
    trainable=True,
    name='input_normalized',
)(inputs)
```

I inferred this from the tensorflow [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization) (which has been updated since the answers above).

Comment: NOTE:  all of the keyword arguments in the example above are defaults.

Comment: This does per-sample normalization though. For batch normalization (normalize independently for each feature, over all samples) use [BatchNormalization layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization) instead (which is what you more likely to want to do on the input, I think.).