# Is there a native 'MinMaxScaler' in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I need to normalize my data with something similar to `sklearn.MinMaxScaler` but I need to use native TensorFlow ONLY and to apply it to TensorFlow `Dataset` API.

How can it be done?

Comment: possibly [tft.scale_by_min_max](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/scale_by_min_max)

Comment: manually see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350684/15893581) Fixed Normalization

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
tf.keras.utils.normalize(x, axis=-1, order=2)
```

The detailed documentation is available here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/normalize

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to the TensorFlow `Dataset` API?

Comment: Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346017/how-to-normalize-input-data-for-models-in-tensorflow/50350684